# Error using EFS in ECS, returns unknown filesystem type 'efs'

Tags: jenkins, terraform, amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

I'm using a docker image for jenkins (jenkins/jenkins:2.277.1-lts-alpine) in an AWS ECS, and I want to persist the data using a AWS EFS.
I created the EFS and got the ID (fs-7dcef848)

My terraform code looks like:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "jenkinsService" {
    cluster = var.ECS_cluster
    name = var.jenkins_name
    task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.jenkinsService.arn
    deployment_maximum_percent = "200"
    deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 50
    desired_count = var.service_desired_count
    tags = {
      "ManagedBy" : "Terraform"
    }
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "jenkinsService" {
  family = "${var.jenkins_name}-task"
  container_definitions = file("task-definitions/service.json")
  volume {
    name  = var.EFS_name
    efs_volume_configuration {
      file_system_id = "fs-7dcef848"
    }
  }
  tags = {
      "ManagedBy" : "Terraform"
  }
}
```

and the service.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "DevOps-jenkins",
    "image": "jenkins/jenkins:2.284-alpine",
    "cpu": 0,
    "memoryReservation": 1024,
    "essential": true,
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort" : 8080,
        "hostPort" : 80
      }
    ],
    "mountPoints": [
      {
          "sourceVolume" : "DevOps-Jenkins",
          "containerPath" : "/var/jenkins_home"
      }
      ]
  }
]
```

The terraform apply works OK, but the task cannot start returning:

**Stopped reason** Error response from daemon: create ecs-DevOps-jenkins-task-33-DevOps-Jekins-bcb381cd9dd0f7ae2700: VolumeDriver.Create: mounting volume failed: mount: unknown filesystem type 'efs'

- Does anyone know whats happening?
- There is another way to persist data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using EC2 or Fargate for AWS ECS? You might need efs filesystem type to be downloaded and configured especially if you are using EC2 type.

Comment: I'm using a EC2

Comment: Okay, you need to setup amazon-efs-utils package for your server. If you have 1 server running you can try manually by connecting the server via ssh, but if you have bunch of servers, you might need to update your USER DATA part in your launch template/configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: The first attempt was to install the "amazon-efs-utils" package using a remote-exec
But following the indications provided by @Oguzhan Aygun , I did it on the USER DATA section and it worked!
Thanks!